# Get hour from datetime and put "Days" in field

Tags: sql-server

Using SQL Server, I have the following:

```
SELECT  DATENAME(DW, DATEADD(DAY, 0, @mindate)) AS Day_of_Week ,
    @crewon AS Crew_On ,
    ISNULL(SUM(( CONVERT(NUMERIC(8, 2), C.FinishLength) / 2000 )), 0) AS Finished_Tons ,
    ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN C.RepairCode LIKE '%A%'
                    THEN ( CONVERT(NUMERIC(8, 2), C.FinishLength)
                           / 2000 )
               END), 0) AS A_Tons
FROM    NYS2SawPieces C
WHERE   RIGHT(C.ShiftIdent, 1) = @crewon
    AND C.ProdTime >= @mindate
    AND C.ProdTime <= DATEADD(DAY, 1, @mindate)
```

I need to get just the "Hours" from `ProdTime` that are from `06` to `18` and put "Days" in the column. Hours outside that range would be "Nights".

Output would like this but add the column for shift.

```
Day_of_Week  Crew_On  Finished_Tons  A_Tons     Shift    
Sunday       A        0.000000       0.0000000  Days
```

Comment: Please edit your question with sample data and desired results.

Comment: I agree with Gordon, however DATEPART is going to be your solution regardless of the specifics

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a CASE statement to apply conditional logic to determine the output:

```
SELECT Col1, Col2,
    CASE WHEN DATEPART(HOUR,C.ProdTime) BETWEEN 6 AND 18 THEN 'DAYS'
         ELSE 'NIGHTS' 
    END AS Shift
FROM....
```

This will output a new column called `Shift` that will output `DAYS` if the value is between 6 and 8, otherwise it will output `NIGHTS`.

Comment: This looked to be the most promising, but when I put it in the select list, I get the error: "Column 'NYS2SawPieces.ProdTime' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause."

Comment: You're using sum aggregation but you don't have any grouping. When using sum, all columns in the select either need an aggregate function applied to them (min,max, count, sum etc) or they need to be grouped. Without seeing some actual source/sample data and desired output it's difficult to advise further.

Comment: Absolutely correct. I combined the requests under one Select statement. When I put the Day/Night query in a separate Select statement, it worked great. Thanks guys for helping.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `WHERE` and `between` sql commands to help you filter your query by the hour, something along the lines of:

```
WHERE hour(your_datetime_field) between 6 and 18
```

The `WHERE` acts as a filter in selecting data that is returned in your query. The rest of the statement is giving the bounds for the hours you want  `your_datetime_field` to be between.

Comment: You may want to include in your answer an explanation of why that will help. Also you should read [this](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common).

Comment: I read that post, very helpful, but not what I need. I need to extract just the hour from the time stamp so that I post the shift worked (Days or Nights) for that crew. In the Where clause I get the crew from the right char of shiftident, and the day of the week from the ProdTime.